# How can I arrange the story of Ibrahim in chronological order?

Tags: tafseer

1. Here is a fragment from the 19th surah:

> And mention in the Book [the story of] Abraham. Indeed, he was a man
> of truth and a prophet. [Mention] when he said to his father, "O my
> father, why do you worship that which does not hear and does not see
> and will not benefit you at all? O my father, indeed there has come to
> me of knowledge that which has not come to you, so follow me; I will
> guide you to an even path. O my father, do not worship [i.e., obey]
> Satan. Indeed Satan has ever been, to the Most Merciful, disobedient.
> O my father, indeed I fear that there will touch you a punishment from
> the Most Merciful so you would be to Satan a companion [in Hellfire].
> [His father] said, "Have you no desire for my gods, O Abraham? If you
> do not desist, I will surely stone you, so avoid me a prolonged time".
> [Abraham] said, "Peace [i.e., safety] will be upon you. I will ask
> forgiveness for you of my Lord. Indeed, He is ever gracious to me. And
> I will leave you and those you invoke other than Allah and will invoke
> my Lord. I expect that I will not be in invocation to my Lord unhappy
> [i.e., disappointed]." (19:41-48)

2. Then comes the second fragment from the 37th surah:

> [And] when he said to his father and his people, "What do you worship?
> Is it falsehood [as] gods other than Allah you desire? Then what is
> your thought about the Lord of the worlds?" And he cast a look at the
> stars. And said, "Indeed, I am [about to be] ill." So they turned away
> from him, departing. Then he turned to their gods and said, "Do you
> not eat?" And he turned upon them a blow with [his] right hand. Then
> they [i.e., the people] came toward him, hastening. He said, "Do you
> worship that which you [yourselves] carve, While Allah created you and
> that which you do?" They said, "Construct for him a structure [i.e.,
> furnace] and throw him into the burning fire." And they intended for
> him a plan [i.e., harm], but We made them the most debased. And [then]
> he said, "Indeed, I will go to [where I am ordered by] my Lord; He
> will guide me. (37:85-99)

**In Surah 19, the father learns about the monotheism of his son Ibrahim, and the father banishes Ibrahim for a long time. And in Surah 37, Ibrahim publicly argues with his father and with his people. How do I arrange these events in chronological order?**

Answer (score 1):

Ibrahim (AS) first preached to his father in private (multiple times), then he preached to his people (multiple times), then only migrated away from them when they stubbornly held on to their religion. He did not just preach once then go away. That is not a thing. What prophet leaves after one conversation?

There are three misunderstandings you have in the first passage:

Firstly, his father asking "Have you no desire for my gods, O Abraham?" does not indicate he is surprised. It's called a rhetorical question. So, this does not have to be the first time his father is hearing of this. But, it can be.

Secondly, leaving doesn't only mean "go away forever." It can simply be "leave your religion" or "leave your way of doing things" or "stay away from your activities" and so on. Then, he continued to preach to his father and his people but only migrated away much later. Or it could be that he left for a time after this conversation, then came back. His father said, "avoid me a prolonged time."

Thirdly, quoted conversations in the Quran can have time skips in them. It is possible this verse "And I will leave you" was said when he was leaving his city, long after he had spent time preaching to his people.

It is important when interpreting the Quran to really question your assumptions. Assumptions are where people make the most mistakes. Why assume this question indicates surprise? Why assume this is one conversation and not a collection of different conversations? Why assume "leave" means physically leave them forever? Always ask yourself: Is another assumption possible and how does that affect my question?

On another note, how many times have you heard of people inviting converts (and even born-Muslims) to Christmas parties? Or it is possible their festival was not directly related to any worship so they thought he should come.

Comment: Can you arrange these events in chronological order in your response to make it clearer?

Comment: @Fath I do not know of any authentic tafsir of this phrase by either Ibn Abbas or any other Sahabi. Not sure what you are referring to. Hopefully you do not mean the tafsir incorrectly attributed to Ibn Abbas found online.

Comment: And what happens in "most cases" does not remove the possibility of another meaning. It is still an assumption. Even if your assumption is likely with the passage taken in isolation, you still have to question it and consider other possibilities (like rhetorical questions) if other verses give you another idea of what happened.

Comment: I provided in my answer possible other views of how to understand this passage. You can use this to come up with many possible chronologies. Feel free to do so yourself.

Comment: 1. I mean tafsir Ibn Qathir. There are the words of Ibn Abbas, Mujahid and others. Take a look at Tafsir Jalalayn. They all take it for a physical act. 
2. Ibn Ashur bluntly calls Father Ibrahim's words amazement. I think the words of such an authoritative imam are sufficient. Al-Alusi also called his father's words surprise and denial. Besides him, Siddiq Khan, Al-Shawkani, Al-Zamakhshari and others also spoke about his surprise. And they are all recognized interpreters of the Koran, and you say that they can all be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150101/discussion-between-the-z-and-fath).